# Linear independence of $X=\{\begin{bmatrix}x_{1}\\ y_{1} \end{bmatrix},...,\begin{bmatrix} x_{k}\\ y_{k} \end{bmatrix}\} \subset \mathbb R^{n+m}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that if the set $T=\{x_1,...,x_k\} \subset \mathbb R^n$ is linearly independent, then $$X=\{\begin{bmatrix}
           x_{1} \\
           y_{1}
         \end{bmatrix},...,\begin{bmatrix}
           x_{k} \\
           y_{k}
         \end{bmatrix}\} \subset \mathbb R^{n+m}\tag{$m \ge 1$}     
$$

is also linearly independent.

---

I assumed that $T=\{x_1,...,x_k\} \subset \mathbb R^n$ is linearly independent, then for some scalars $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_k$ let $$\sum_{j=1}^{k}\lambda_j\begin{bmatrix}
           x_{j} \\
           y_{j}
         \end{bmatrix}=0$$

Which is equivalent to $$\sum_{j=1}^{k}\lambda_j\begin{bmatrix}
           x_{j} \\
           0
         \end{bmatrix}+\sum_{j=1}^{k}\lambda_j\begin{bmatrix}
           0 \\
           y_{j}
         \end{bmatrix}=0$$

Now how to use the assumption to show that all such scalars are zero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, $$\lambda \left [\begin{array}{c}x\\y\end{array} \right ] = \left [\begin{array}{c}\lambda x \\ \lambda y\end{array} \right ] \quad\mbox{and}\quad \left [\begin{array}{c}x \\y\end{array} \right ] + \left [\begin{array}{c}u\\v\end{array} \right ] = \left [\begin{array}{c}x+u \\ y+v\end{array} \right ]$$
where $x,y,u,v\in\mathbb R^n$ and $\lambda\in\mathbb R$. Effectively, these are matrix arithmetic rules. Conclude that
$$\left [\begin{array}{c}0\\0\end{array} \right ]= \sum \lambda _k \left [\begin{array}{c}x_k\\y_k\end{array} \right ] = \left [\begin{array}{c}\sum \lambda _kx_k \\ \sum \lambda _ky_k\end{array} \right ], $$
where $0\in \mathbb R^n$ is the zero. In particular, $\sum \lambda _kx_k = 0$.

Comment: So in the end you used the linearly independence of $T=\{x_1,...,x_k\}$?

Comment: @masaheb Correct.

Comment: About this question, does the converse hold?

Comment: @masaheb If two matrices are linearly independent, that does not imply all their respective rows are linearly independent.

Comment: @ AlvinL,
For the counterexample we can take $x_1,y_2=1,x_2,y_1=0$, then from  $$\lambda_1\begin{bmatrix}
           1 \\
           0
         \end{bmatrix}+\lambda_2 \begin{bmatrix}
           0 \\
           1
         \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
           0 \\
           0
         \end{bmatrix}$$

We conclude that the vectors are linearly independent, however if we take $0,-2$ as scalars, then $0x_1-2x_2=0(1)-2(0)=0$ , and this shows that $x_1$ and $x_2$ are not linearly independent, is the argument correct?

Comment: @masaheb Correct. Any system that contains the zero  is linearly dependent. Take row vectors $A,B$ that are linearly independent then the matrices $(0,A)$ and $(0,B)$ are also independent. But the first rows are dependent.